# Android tethering, how to disable dhcp

Tags: android, android-ndk, wifi, dhcp

Using WifiManger and reflection(to find the enablewifiap() method), I am able to enable wifi tethering to create a wifi hotspot.

However, I would like to **disable** DHCP for the other devices that will connect to the phone that is acting as the hotspot. 
I am not able to find any functions that would achieve this.
Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no functions exposed via [`WifiManager`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java&q=WifiManager&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc), [`WifiService`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/services/java/com/android/server/WifiService.java&q=WifiService&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) and [`NetworkManagementService`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/services/java/com/android/server/NetworkManagementService.java&q=NetworkManagementService&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) that can disable DHCP for Wi-Fi AP (as far as I can see from thecode). You can inspect [`NetworkManagementService`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/services/java/com/android/server/NetworkManagementService.java&q=NetworkManagementService&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc)'s code closer (especially [`setAccessPoint`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/services/java/com/android/server/NetworkManagementService.java&q=NetworkManagementService&l=659) function) if you interested in implementation details.

Comment: Is there any way to do this through the NDK?
Perhaps killing the daemon that deals with the DHCP (if it exists).

Comment: What about looking at netstat and getting the process using port 67?